# Search and replace a string using Windows shell or Perl script

Tags: perl, search, cmd

How can i search for `//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt            #10`
and replace `#10` with `#15` (set VARIABLE="#15") using batch commands and also **ignoring spaces**. `#10` can be anything, lets assume `#XXX`.

**testlog.txt**

```
   //packages/thirdparty/release/config.txt                    #8
   //packages/thirdparty/release/config2.txt   #3
   //packages/thirdparty/release/config1.txt    #4
   //packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt            #10
```

This is my try

```
@ECHO OFF
set $FindStr=//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt#10
set $ReplString=//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt#15

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type testlog.txt') do (
   set $Ver=%%a
   set $Ver=!$Ver: =!
   If /i !$Ver!==%$FindStr% set $Ver=%$ReplString%
   echo !$Ver! ) >> testlog.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a one line Perl:

```
perl -pe"s!(//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt *)#\d+!$1#15!;" testlog.txt
```

replaces `#10` by `#15`

Comment: thank you Miguel for replying, but #10 can be any number and i would only like to replace"   //packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt            #XX" with #15

Comment: Thanks ikegami and Miguel.

Comment: one more quick question, suppose  "//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt" is variable in bash script. How can i use it in above script?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by *"ignoring spaces"*. I assume they are in the original file, so you can't ignore them.

In a Perl one-liner, this keeps whatever spaces were there before the `#99` field, and changes it to `#15`.

```
perl -pe"s|//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt\s*\K#\d+|#15|" testlog.txt
```

---

The `\K` ("keep") construct requires version 10 or later of Perl 5. If you have an earlier version and cannot update, then you can use a capture and replace instead, like this

```
perl -pe"s|(//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt\s*)#\d+|$1#15|" testlog.txt
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't work. It seems like something is missing.

Comment: `\K` requires Perl 5.10 or newer.