# perl regex with variables

Tags: regex, perl

```
set release=//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt

perl -pe"s!(//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt *)#\d+!$1#15!;" testlog.txt
```

How can I use `%release%` (environment variable `release`) instead of `//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt`?

I'm getting syntax error from

```
 perl -pe"s!(%release%! *)#\d+!$1#15!;" testlog.txt
```

original question 
[Search and replace a string using Windows shell or Perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971874/search-and-replace-a-string-using-windows-shell-or-perl-script/28973116#28973116)

Comment: Avinash, thank you for your help but answer provided by "Borodin" worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `%ENV` hash to access environment variables, like this

```
perl -pe"s/(\Q$ENV{RELEASE}\E *)#\d+/$1#15/" testlog.txt
```

You can also use a positive look-behind to avoid having to replace the initial string

```
perl -pe"s/(?<=\Q$ENV{RELEASE}\E *)#\d+/#15/" testlog.txt
```

or `\K` if you are running version 14 or later of Perl 5

```
perl -pe"s/\Q$ENV{RELEASE}\E *\K#\d+/#15/" testlog.txt
```